# Using XML ElementTree to create list of objects with atrributes

Tags: python, xml, class, object, elementtree

I use the python requests module to get XML from the TeamCity rest api that looks like this:

```
<triggers count="10">
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1240" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt191"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1241" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt171"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1242" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt167"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1243" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt164"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1244" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt364"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_736" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="Components_Ratchetdb"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_149" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="Components_Filedb"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_150" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="bt168"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="TRIGGER_1130" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
    <properties count="2">
        <property name="afterSuccessfulBuildOnly" value="true"/>
        <property name="dependsOn" value="Components_Tbldb"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
<trigger id="vcsTrigger" type="vcsTrigger" inherited="true">
    <properties count="3">
        <property name="quietPeriod" value="60"/>
        <property name="quietPeriodMode" value="USE_DEFAULT"/>
        <property name="triggerRules" value="-:version.properties&#xA;-:comment=^Incremented:**&#xA;-:**/*-schema.sql"/>
    </properties>
</trigger>
```

I am trying to create a list of "trigger" objects using a class. Ideally the object would have id, type, and a list of properties attributes as dictionaries of {name : value}.  My code so far is:

```
class triggerList:
     def __init__(self, triggerId, triggerType):
         self.id = triggerId
         self.type = triggerType
         self.properties = []

     def add_property(self, buildProperty):
         self.properties.append(buildProperty)

def getAllTriggers(buildId):
     url = path + 'buildTypes/id:' + buildId + '/triggers'
     r = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
     tree = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)
     listOfTriggers = []

     for trigger in tree.iter('trigger'):
         triggerType = trigger.get('type')
         triggerId = trigger.get('id')
         triggerName = str(triggerId)
         triggerName = triggerList(triggerId, triggerType)
         listOfTriggers.append(triggerName)

         for triggerProperty in tree.iter('property'):
             propertyName = triggerProperty.get('name')
             propertyValue = triggerProperty.get('value')
             propDict = {propertyName : propertyValue}
             triggerName.add_property(propDict)
```

This gives me a list of objects but every object has a list of every property dictionary.  This is the output:

```
a = listOfTriggers[1]
print a.id, a.type, a.properties

>>>  TRIGGER_1241 buildDependencyTrigger [{'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt191'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt171'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt167'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt164'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt364'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'Components_Ratchetdb'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'Components_Filedb'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'bt168'}, {'afterSuccessfulBuildOnly': 'true'}, {'dependsOn': 'Components_Tbldb'}, {'quietPeriod': '60'}, {'quietPeriodMode': 'USE_DEFAULT'}, {'triggerRules': '-:version.properties\n-:comment=^Incremented:**\n-:**/*-schema.sql'}]
```

I don't know how to stop the loop for just the properties for a specific trigger.  Is there a way to use ElementTree to only get the properties for a specific trigger?  Is there a more efficient way to create this object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly answering the question, but you may be reinventing the wheel here, check [`lxml.objectify` package](http://lxml.de/objectify.html):

> The main idea is to hide the usage of XML behind normal Python
>   objects, sometimes referred to as data-binding. It allows you to use
>   XML as if you were dealing with a normal Python object hierarchy.
>   Accessing the children of an XML element deploys object attribute
>   access. If there are multiple children with the same name, slicing and
>   indexing can be used. Python data types are extracted from XML content
>   automatically and made available to the normal Python operators.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this!

Answer (score 0):

Simple syntax mistake:

```
for triggerProperty in trigger.iter('property'):
        propertyName = triggerProperty.get('name')
        propertyValue = triggerProperty.get('value')
        propDict = {propertyName : propertyValue}
        triggerName.add_property(propDict)
```

I was iterating over the whole tree, rather than the triggers.  Should be:

for triggerProperty in **trigger**.iter('property'):